# Remove deleted posts from the edit review queue

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

I came across a suggested edit ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15890348) if you must know, although my question is not about this particular edit.)

But the post itself has been deleted after the edit was suggested, so the edit wouldn't have been valid any more.
(People with >10k rep, who can see deleted posts, can also edit them, but those edits don't end up in the reviews, so that isn't the problem. The problem is suggested edits by <2k people to posts that get deleted before the edit goes through.)

My request, therefore, is to have pending edits deleted from the reviews whenever a post is deleted, so that people will no longer have to spend time deciding whether to let them go through or not.